# How to create and print multi level dictionary in python?

Tags: python

Data structure required:

```
Name -->gene1
             --> CDS
                     1   3
                     6   10
             --> exon
                     4   8
       ->gene2
             --> CDS
                     4   9
```

I am trying to create and print the above data structure using python Dictionaries. I am very new to Python that's why I not able create it. Need help to create it.

Try:

```
dict = {'name' :{'gene1': {'CDS' : [1, 3]}}}
for name in dict:
        print name
        for gene in dict[name]:
                print "\t" +gene
                for feature in dict[name][gene]:
                        print "\t\t"+feature
                        print "\t\t\t",
                        print dict[name][gene][feature]
```

output:

```
name
        gene1
                CDS
                        [1, 3]
```

Comment: So... what precisely is the *problem* with what you have? You seem to have created a multi-level dictionary just fine, and it's printing out exactly how you asked it to.

Comment: First and Important, don't use dict as the var name, dict is special word in python

Comment: @jonrsharpe: My required data structure has two gene (gene1 and gene2) and the CDS has two rows.I am having problem in that part of the dictionary.

Comment: Where you need to have multiple values for the same key, make the value a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dct = {"gene1": {"CDS": [[1, 3], [6, 10]], "exon": [[4, 8]]}, "gene2": {"CDS": [[4, 9]]}}

for outer_key, outer_value in dct.items():
    print(outer_key)
    for inner_key, inner_value in outer_value.items():
        print("\t", inner_key)
        for elem in inner_value:
            print("\t\t", elem)
```

Your question is very unclear, but here is a possible solution.

`items()` in python2 is `iteritems()`

This will output:

```
gene2
         CDS
                 [4, 9]
gene1
         CDS
                 [1, 3]
                 [6, 10]
         exon
                 [4, 8]
```

The `gene1` `gene2` is the key in the outer dict, `CDS` and `exon` are inner dicts (values of the outer dict) and their values are lists (nested lists)